# Troubleshooting Connection Errors w/ AppEngine Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine

does anyone have any tips on how to troubleshoot connection errors on appengine ?

I've been running a cron job on appengine that makes couple of PayPal API calls for almost about a month, and just recently started seeing the deanline exceeded errors, which seems to be due to ConnectionError. The api.paypal.com is our live/production server and none of our other monitors are failing - so this makes me think that it's something specific to appengine.

Any tips on how to troubleshoot this ? We don't really see anything on our server side - so unless something else upstream at network level is blocking the connections.

File "/base/data/home/apps/s~pp-stashboard/10.371471577236231745/requests/adapters.py", line 356, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e)

HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.paypal.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded
with url: /v1/oauth2/token (Caused by :
Deadline exceeded while waiting for HTTP response from URL:
https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try running your API calls through RunScope to debug them.

Comment: Also, there was some recent downtime with Urlfetch - is this related to you? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-downtime-notify/aRJ9F1FJv2o

Comment: Yup - seems like it - I don't the errors as frequently as they were reported until 10:30 AM. I still see them occasionally though -

Comment: like this one at 2:11PM -

2013-11-07 14:11:22.843
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.paypal.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/oauth2/login (Caused by <class 'httplib.HTTPException'>